# Adal Typescript file

Tags: typescript, adal

I am trying to use the typescript version of adal.js.

I am following the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-typescript) to download adal.ts. But, after running the command

```
npm install adal-typescript --save
```

a new folder "node_modules" are created in the solution. But, it seems that none of them have the implementations. Am I going in the right direction or have I missed something?

Comment: yes this is how node modules work.now you can import adal file

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha But, node modules contain many files. Which file should I import?

Comment: you only need to import files you need.for example if you want to use authcontext do `import { AuthenticationContext } from "adal...";`

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, so when we deploy the JS (after compiling from TS), do we need to add adal-ts code too in CRM?

Comment: no never upload node modules.no need to upload typescript either since browser don't  understand ts. when you compile it will create concat , minified version of required files.but it depend on your setup.if you have build tools like webpack , gulp ,grunt you can configure them .

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of NPM install command.

Running `npm install` in production server cannot be done in certain scenario (lack of compiling tools, restricted internet access, etc...) and also if you have to deploy the same project on multiple machines, can be a waste of cpu, memory and bandwidth.

You should run `npm install --production` on a machine with the same libraries and node version of the production server, compress node_modules and deploy on production server. You should also keep the `package-lock.json` file to pinpoint versions.

This approach allows you also to build/test your code using development packages and then pruning the `node_modules` before the actual deploy.

Moving node_modules folder is overkilled. Running npm install might break the version dependencies. The best approach is `npm ci`. It uses the `package_lock` file and installs the required dependencies without modify the versions. `npm ci` meant for continuous integration projects. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, is this method recommended if we need to deploy our TS code to CRM?